# Can't load anyone other than Michael on Xbox one

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

On Xbox one, for GTA V, I cannot load and a character other than Michael. I tried loading from the online character, and it brings me right back to Michael regardless of who I select. It doesn't give me the option to select another character wall in Michael's  for start animation, can someone help please?

Comment: No. Sorry it is about GTA V

Comment: Where are you at in the game? Isn't there a point where you have to use Michael to progress?

Comment: I'm not sure what I did right, but I did some cab missions, and it eventually fixed itself. I am at the FIB heist involving the fire truck.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on the PC. It took me a couple of days but switching from online to offline and doing cab missions seems to be the trick. I hope one of these options works for you